How can you create an input with Line Thickness images as the dropdown options using PineScript?
To clarify I am trying to recreate the input as it appears on the default Fib Retracement drawing tool

I do not understand what they are using to represent those thick lines, are they using a string input and pasting as the menu options lines of different thickness?
To recreate the line styles you can just use "----" or ". . . ." but I don't get how to represent the widths/thickness

You cannot do that. Fib Retracement is a drawing tool. Not every drawing tools or even built-in indicators on Tradingview are created in Pinescript.
Just use a input.int() instead.
